# DropDownList and RequiredFieldValidator control

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-3.5

I am using dropdownlist control and a RequiredFieldValidator control for that ddl  inside the gridview.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInsert" runat="server" CssClass="normal" DataSourceID="sqlDataSource" DataTextField="Name"  DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ID") %>'  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
              <asp:ListItem  Text="--Select--" Value="-1" Selected="True" />
              </asp:DropDownList>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredDDL" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlInsertRegion" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="-1" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But this validator is not working

Comment: I guess he shouldn't. B-Rain's answer is correct, I verified it with a datasource-less DDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ControlToValidate="ddlInsertRegion" in the validator but the DropDownList control ID is ID="ddlInsert"

Comment: Thank you. I have missed the validationgroup property.